# 3D Heat Plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, heatmap

I am trying to create a 3d heat decay plot in matlab and need to know how to do it. I have 10 points in space that decay over time. The decay is shown in z axis as time axis.Y-axis shows temperature and x axis has those 10 points. I have attached an image of what I want. I already have the data and need to plot it in format as shown in image.

Data:

Points in space

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

Time in sec

t = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

Temperature Data

y = [

```
 [500, 400, 600, 700, 800, 500, 600, 800, 300, 200]

 [400, 300, 600, 700, 200, 500, 900, 800, 300, 800]

 [300, 600, 600, 700, 800, 500, 600, 900, 300, 200]

 [200, 400, 300, 600, 500, 100, 900, 800, 300, 700]

 [400, 400, 600, 300, 800, 500, 600, 600, 200, 200]
```

]

[Heat Decay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkeH7.png)

Comment: Welcome to the site! The question is currently too broad (see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). I think you want to use [`mesh`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mesh.html); see the examples there. Then you can try to implement what you describe, and then ask if you have a specific question about that

Comment: your `x` axis is a `[10x1]` vector, your `z` (or `t`) axis is also a `[10x1]` vector. If your `y` data were temperature for each of the point defined by the full `x-z` grid, then your `y` matrix should be of size: `[10x10]`.

Comment: Another thing: Your temperature data contained in `y` do not represent a _decay_. Whether you take the data by rows or columns, the temperature goes up and down. Even when plotted once your axis are better defined, you will not get the same shape of surface you linked as a result.